# How can I use Spring framework in to my Android project?

Tags: android, spring

Theoritically I bit understand spring framework. but I want to know how to use it in Android project. If possible can I have an example .

Comment: What benefits are you expecting from using Spring in Android?

Answer (score 3):

If you need IOC, you need to take a look at roboguice (hosted on googlecode)

If you need spring small tools like [`RestTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) there's a spring-android project.

- [spring-android home](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android)
- [roboguice home](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/)